# Delete lines starting with a unique number

Tags: python, unique, repeat

I'm learning Python and created this program, but it won't work and I'm hoping someone can find the error!

I have a file that has entries like this:

```
0 Kurthia sibirica Planococcaceae   
1593 Lactobacillus hordei Lactobacillaceae   
1121 Lactobacillus coleohominis Lactobacillaceae   
614 Lactobacillus coryniformis Lactobacillaceae   
57 Lactobacillus kitasatonis Lactobacillaceae   
3909 Lactobacillus malefermentans Lactobacillaceae
```

My goal is to remove all the lines that start with a number that only occurs once in the whole file (unique numbers), and save all the lines that start with number occurring twice or more to a new file. This is my attempt. It doesn't work yet (when I let the `print` line work, one line from the whole files repeated 3 times and that's it):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

infilename = 'v35.clusternum.species.txt'
outfilename = 'v13clusters.no.singletons.txt'

#remove extra letters and spaces
x = 0
with open(infilename, 'r') as infile, open(outfilename, 'w') as outfile:
        for line in infile:
                clu, gen, spec, fam = line.split()
        for clu in line:
                if clu.count > 1:
                        #print line
                        outfile.write(line)
                else:
                    x += 1
print("Number of Singletons:")
print(x)
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, your code is kind of headed in the right direction, but you have a few things decidedly confused.

You need to separate what your script is doing into two logical steps: one, aggregating (counting) all of the `clu` fields.  Two, writing each field that has a `clu` count of > 1.  You tried to do these steps together at the same time and.. well, it didn't work.  You can technically do it that way, but you have the syntax wrong.  It's also terribly inefficient to continuously search through your file for stuff.  Best to only do it once or twice.

So, let's separate the steps.  First, count up your `clu` fields.  The `collections` module has a `Counter` that you can use.

```
from collections import Counter
with open(infilename, 'r') as infile:
    c = Counter(line.split()[0] for line in infile)
```

`c` is now a `Counter` that you can use to look up the count of a given `clu`.

```
with open(infilename, 'r') as infile, open(outfilename, 'w') as outfile:
        for line in infile:
                clu, gen, spec, fam = line.split()
                if c[clu] > 1:
                    outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: I think you mean `Counter(line.split()[0] for line in infile)`?

Comment: @roippi Thanks for this, it's perfect! I'm wondering if you could suggest one more thing: getting a count of the 'number of numbers' that were removed. So if the lines starting with `0` and `57` from the example in my question only appeared once, my 'sum of numbers' would be 2. I tried to do this and inserted an `else: print([clu])` put it just prints the numbers that were removed.

Comment: @roippi I thought I edited my question (to show you my `else: print` attempt), I accidentally added it to your answer, I'm sorry!!

Comment: @roippi wait, I think I figured it out (It gave me a number at least haha) I added my 'number of numbers' code to my question. Thanks for your help!

Comment: since the only field actually used is the number, *partition* is preferred over *split* I would replace the 3rd line of the second snippet with
clu = line.partition[0]. Actually - in the first snippet , 3rd line too